# multiple queries java jdbc - read records simultaneously

Tags: java, jdbc

I have multiple queries that I would like to read data from simultaneously using java JDBC connection to an SQL server.

In a single query, I know that you can loop through the records as follows

```
while (rs.next()){
  //get record and do stuff
}
```

however, if I have multiple recordsets how can I do this for each one simultaneously.  Each resultset is the same length.  I actually made an array of resultsets thinking that I could loop over the resultsets, as below...

```
for (int i = 0;i<NUM_RECORDSETS;i++){
 while(rs[i].next()){
    //get stuff from this recordset
  }
}
```

...but I don't want to loop through one at a time. I'd like to be able to have the cursor position for each resultset move synchronously.  Is there a method that I can use to move the cursor manually, or what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a scenario like this:

```
Record pos :  0 |  1 |  2 |  3
ResultSet-1: A1 | B1 | C1 | D1
ResultSet-2: A2 | B2 | C2 | D2
ResultSet-3: A3 | B3 | C3 | D3
```

And you want to iterate over results in this order:

```
A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, ...
```

The code you originally posted would iterate in this order:

```
A1, B1, C1, D1, A2, ...
```

Simply move the for loop inside the while loop to achieve that pattern:

```
while(rs.length > 0 && !rs[0].isAfterLast()){
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RECORDSETS; i++){
        rs[i].next();
        //get stuff from this recordset
    }
}
```

If I misunderstood your question, and you want to *concurrently* read result sets (as in multi-threaded), I would strongly discourage doing that.